# What does "ad minūtim" mean? Does it mean the same as "minūtus"?

Tags: meaning

I understand that minūtim is a conjugation of minūtus. Is that correct?

What does "ad minūtim" mean and what would minūtus mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: *minutim* is an adverb derived from the past participle *minutus* (from *minuo*) plus the suffix *-im*, used to form adverbs with a distributive meaning often derived from past participles (such as *cursim* or *festinatim*)

While the adjectival participle *minutus* can mean 'minute', 'slender', 'thin', 'small', 'short', the adverb *minutim* can mean 'a little at a time', 'in small parts',' minutely', like the equivalent *minute* and *minutatim*.

The most correct locution is therefore not *ad minutim* (which is also fairly [widespread](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ad%20minutim%22&client=firefox-b-d&ei=mIsBYbLRLJCasAf0tJ_4Dg&oq=%22ad%20minutim%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEA0QHjoHCAAQsAMQHkoECEEYAVCKqR5YzKkeYOqrHmgBcAB4AIABf4gBsQKSAQMxLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiy_cyinYbyAhUQDewKHXTaB-8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5)), but *ad minutum* (which I do not think is of classical use): *vendere ad minutum* means 'to retail' (cfr. Du Cange et al., *Glossarium mediae et infimae latinitatis*, s.v. *[retaiare](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/RETAIARE)*).

To learn more about the various shades of meaning of the adverb *minutim* you can check the *Thesaurus linguae Latinae* s.v. [*minuo*, col. 1044,17-35](http://To%20learn%20more%20about%20the%20various%20shades%20of%20meaning%20you%20can%20check%20the%20lemma%20minutus%20in%20the%20Thesaurus%20linguae%20Latinae%20(https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#59508)).